# Python ctypes union, string, str, byte: three Pythons, three different results

Tags: python, ctypes

A colleague was asked to provide a starting point for socket client and server applications that I could adapt to our customer's needs.  He provided something a lot fancier than I expected, and provided an excellent lesson in Python programming for me.

But he targeted his programs to Python 2.7.  I have spent my entire time at this company trying to drag it into the 20th century.  (Note that I didn't say 21st.)  I want to use Python 3.2 (not 3.5 because everybody but me uses PythonWin, which won't work with 3.5.  I use PyCharm).

The code supplied by my colleague uses the ctypes module's Structure and Union classes.  In Python 3.2, the first line of the `__init__` method throws this exception:  TypeError:  expected string, str found.  In Python 3.5, the error is "TypeError:  expected bytes, str found."  In Python 2.7, there is no error and the code works.

This is my first encounter with the ctypes module, and I only met Python 3 when I began this project.  Can someone tell me what I need to do to get this to work?

Here's the code:

```
class AliveMsg(Structure):
    """
    """
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("Header", MsgHeader),  # Header
                ("EndFlag", c_char * 1)]  # End Flag always '#'


class TransAlive(Union):
    length = 49

    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("Struct", AliveMsg),
                ("Message", c_char * 49),
                ("Initialize", c_char * 49)]

    def __init__(self):
        self.Initialize = ' ' * 49
        self.Struct.Header.START_FLAG = '*'
        self.Struct.Header.SEP1 = ';'
        self.Struct.Header.SEP2 = ';'
        self.Struct.Header.SEP3 = ';'
        self.Struct.Header.SEP4 = ';'
        self.Struct.Header.HEADER_END = 'Data:'
        self.Struct.EndFlag = '#'
```

Comment: PythonWin works with 3.5.  I use it.

Comment: In that case, my problem was probably that I did not uninstall 3.2 before installing 3.5.  PythonWin insisted on using 3.2.

Comment: You have to install `pywin32` for each version of Python, and the last one installed will be the default Pythonwin launched when right-clicking a script and selecting "Edit with Pythonwin".  I end up editing the registry to add right-click shortcuts to the individual versions I have installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use byte strings instead of Unicode strings for `c_char`.  Unicode strings are the default in Python 3, but byte strings are the default in Python 2.  For example:

```
self.Initialize = b' ' * 49
```

If you assign text to `Message`, to use non-ASCII you can use a Unicode string but encode it to a byte string in an appropriate encoding:

```
self.Message = 'Some Chinese: 马克'.encode('utf8')
```

Comment: Note that 2.6/2.7 will ignore the `b` prefix, if you need to support 2.x and 3.x together.